# Showing that the function $(Tf)(x) = \int_0^{x} f(y) dy$ is continuous on $[0,1]$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $H = L^{2} ([0, 1], \lambda)$ be the Hilbert space of square integrable functions on $[0,1]$. Define the operator $$ T: H \rightarrow H: (Tf)(x) = \int_0^{x} f(y) dy $$ for all $f \in L^{2}([0,1], \lambda), x \in [0,1]$.

**Problem:** Prove that $Tf$ actually belongs to $L^{2}([0,1])$ by proving that for all $f \in L^{2}([0,1], \lambda)$, $Tf$ is in fact a continuous function on $[0,1]$.

**Attempt:** Let $f \in L^{2}([0,1], \lambda)$ and let $x \in [0,1]$. I wish to show that $Tf$ is continuous at $x$.

Let $\epsilon > 0$. I need to find a $\delta > 0$ such that for all $z \in [0,1]$ with $|x-z| < \delta$, we have that $$ | (Tf)(x) - (Tf)(z)| < \epsilon. $$

I don't really know how to find this $\delta$. I have $$| (Tf)(x) - (Tf)(z)| = \bigg| \int_0^{x} f(y) dy - \int_0^{z} f(y)dy \bigg|. $$ If I assume that $z < x$, then I can estimate this as $$\bigg| \int_0^{x} f(y) dy - \int_0^{z} f(y)dy \bigg| \leq \int_z^{x} | f(y)| dy. $$

I'm not sure how to pick $\delta$ such that this is arbitrary small. Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Use that $|\int_z^xf(y)dy|^2 \leq (\int_z^x|f(y)|dy)^2 \leq |x-z|||f||^2_2,\forall x,y \in [0.1]$ by Cauchy-Schwartz inequality.

You can prove it also with Dominated Convergence:

Let $x_n \to x$

Then  $f_n(y)=f(y)1_{[0,x_n]}(y) \to f(y)1_{[0,x]}(y)$ pointwise.

Also $|f_n| \leq |f|\in L^2[0,1]$

So by Dominated convergence you hace the conclusion.

Comment: I don't see how you get that inequality from Cauchy-Schwarz. CS says $|\langle x, y \rangle | \leq || x || || y ||$. So that means I can say that $\langle f, 1 \rangle = \int_0^{1} f(z) dz \leq ||f||_2$?

Comment: @Kamil we use the function $1_{[z,x]}$ in the inner product and not 1

Comment: @ Marios: Schwarz and not Swartz !